# 'mining' msbuild project files for configuration information

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I'm trying to write an MSBuild script which I can import from an existing script (generated using visual studio), and run via MSBuild to extract configuration information (`CLCompile`, `Link`, `Lib`, etc)

My idea is that the `SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetProjectConfiguration` target will get run once per Configuration/Platform combination, and for each one, it will run MSBuild recursively on the project file multiple times, getting 1 item from each mentioned item list each time. This item should have 'default' metadata as set for that configuration (thanks to project's `ItemDefinitionGroup`s)

I'm pretty new to MSBuild, and I've got the following so far, but it doesn't really seem to work like I expect. Inside the inline task, I get 4 items, instead of just 1(I'm guessing I don't understand Target/Task batching properly...), and they only have default metadata, instead of things that `CLCompile`, `Link`, etc would have. Their Identity *is* 'XXX_SHOULD_BE_UNIQUE' though...

If there's a better approach for this which doesn't involve the visual studio GUI, that would be great as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >
  <UsingTask TaskName="LogItem" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Items ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Required="true" />
      <ItemName Required="true" />
      <ItemKey Required="true" />
      <ItemLog Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
<![CDATA[
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // So I can debug, comment out to prevent the build from failing.
        bool found = false;
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
          if (item.GetMetadata("Identity") == ItemKey)
          {
            if (found) return false;
            found = true;

            ItemLog = ItemName + "\n";
            foreach (var key in item.MetadataNames)
            {
              if ("Identity" == key) continue;
              ItemLog = ItemLog + (String)key + ": " + item.GetMetadata((String)key) + "\n";
            }
          }
        }

        return found;
]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <UniqueKey>XXX_SHOULD_BE_UNIQUE</UniqueKey>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetProjectConfiguration" Outputs="@(ProjectConfiguration->'%(Configuration)|%(Platform)')" >
    <Message Text="%(ProjectConfiguration.Configuration)|%(ProjectConfiguration.Platform)" />
    <MSBuild
      Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      Targets="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetCLCompile"
      Properties="Configuration=%(ProjectConfiguration.Configuration);Platform=%(ProjectConfiguration.Platform)" >
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="CLCompileTemplate" />
    </MSBuild>
    <LogItem Items="@(CLCompileTemplate)" ItemKey="$(UniqueKey)" ItemName="CLCompile" >
      <Output TaskParameter="ItemLog" PropertyName="CLCompileTemplateLog" />
    </LogItem>
    <MSBuild
      Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      Targets="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetLink"
      Properties="Configuration=%(ProjectConfiguration.Configuration);Platform=%(ProjectConfiguration.Platform)" >
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="LinkTemplate" />
    </MSBuild>
    <LogItem Item="@(LinkTemplate)" ItemKey="$(UniqueKey)" ItemName="Link" >
      <Output TaskParameter="ItemLog" PropertyName="LinkTemplateLog" />
    </LogItem>
    <MSBuild
      Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      Targets="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetLib"
      Properties="Configuration=%(ProjectConfiguration.Configuration);Platform=%(ProjectConfiguration.Platform)" >
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="LibTemplate" />
    </MSBuild>
    <LogItem Item="@(LibTemplate)" ItemKey="$(UniqueKey)" ItemName="Lib" >
      <Output TaskParameter="ItemLog" PropertyName="LibTemplateLog" />
    </LogItem>
    <MSBuild
      Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      Targets="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetResourceCompile"
      Properties="Configuration=%(ProjectConfiguration.Configuration);Platform=%(ProjectConfiguration.Platform)" >
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="ResourceCompileTemplate" />
    </MSBuild>
    <LogItem Item="@(ResourceCompileTemplate)" ItemKey="$(UniqueKey)" ItemName="ResourceCompile" >
      <Output TaskParameter="ItemLog" PropertyName="ResourceCompileTemplateLog" />
    </LogItem>
    <MSBuild
      Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      Targets="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetProjectReference"
      Properties="Configuration=%(ProjectConfiguration.Configuration);Platform=%(ProjectConfiguration.Platform)" >
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="ProjectReferenceTemplate" />
    </MSBuild>
    <LogItem Item="@(ProjectReferenceTemplate)" ItemKey="$(UniqueKey)" ItemName="ProjectReference" >
      <Output TaskParameter="ItemLog" PropertyName="ProjectReferenceTemplateLog" />
    </LogItem>
    <MSBuild
      Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      Targets="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetPostBuildEvent"
      Properties="Configuration=%(ProjectConfiguration.Configuration);Platform=%(ProjectConfiguration.Platform)" >
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="PostBuildEventTemplate" />
    </MSBuild>
    <LogItem Item="@(PostBuildEventTemplate)" ItemKey="$(UniqueKey)" ItemName="PostBuildEvent" >
      <Output TaskParameter="ItemLog" PropertyName="PostBuildEventTemplateLog" />
    </LogItem>
    <MSBuild
      Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
      Targets="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetMidl"
      Properties="Configuration=%(ProjectConfiguration.Configuration);Platform=%(ProjectConfiguration.Platform)" >
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="MidlTemplate" />
    </MSBuild>
    <LogItem Item="@(MidlTemplate)" ItemKey="$(UniqueKey)" ItemName="Midl" >
      <Output TaskParameter="ItemLog" PropertyName="MidlTemplateLog" />
    </LogItem>

    <Message Text="%(ProjectConfiguration.Configuration)|%(ProjectConfiguration.Platform)" />
    <Message Text="$(CLCompileTemplateLog)" />
    <Message Text="$(LinkTemplateLog)" />
    <Message Text="$(LibTemplateLog)" />
    <Message Text="$(ResourceCompileTemplateLog)" />
    <Message Text="$(ProjectReferenceTemplateLog)" />
    <Message Text="$(PostBuildEventTemplateLog)" />
    <Message Text="$(MidlTemplateLog)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetCLCompile" Returns="@(CLCompileTemplate)" >
    <ItemGroup>
      <CLCompile Include="$(UniqueKey)" />
      <CLCompileTemplate Include="%(CLCompile.Identity)" Condition="'%(CLCompile.Identity)'=='$(UniqueKey)'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetLink" Returns="@(LinkTemplate)" >
    <ItemGroup>
      <Link Include="$(UniqueKey)" />
      <LinkTemplate Include="%(Link.Identity)" Condition="'%(Link.Identity)'=='$(UniqueKey)'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetLib" Returns="@(LibTemplate)" >
    <ItemGroup>
      <Lib Include="$(UniqueKey)" />
      <LibTemplate Include="%(Lib.Identity)" Condition="'%(Lib.Identity)'=='$(UniqueKey)'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetResourceCompile" Returns="@(ResourceCompileTemplate)" >
    <ItemGroup>
      <ResourceCompile Include="$(UniqueKey)" />
      <ResourceCompileTemplate Include="%(ResourceCompile.Identity)" Condition="'%(ResourceCompile.Identity)'=='$(UniqueKey)'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetProjectReference" Returns="@(ProjectReferenceTemplate)" >
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="$(UniqueKey)" />
      <ProjectReferenceTemplate Include="%(ProjectReference.Identity)" Condition="'%(ProjectReference.Identity)'=='$(UniqueKey)'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetPostBuildEvent" Returns="@(PostBuildEventTemplate)" >
    <ItemGroup>
      <PostBuildEvent Include="$(UniqueKey)" />
      <PostBuildEventTemplate Include="%(PostBuildEvent.Identity)" Condition="'%(PostBuildEvent.Identity)'=='$(UniqueKey)'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetMidl" Returns="@(MidlTemplate)" >
    <ItemGroup>
      <Midl Include="$(UniqueKey)" />
      <MidlTemplate Include="%(Midl.Identity)" Condition="'%(Midl.Identity)'=='$(UniqueKey)'" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

You can test it out by `Import`ing this file at the bottom of the project file you want to use.

Comment: What's the detail result you got and you expect? I modify the code, you can check it here: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AresBGZVYryjhR3aJ9-CHelZMBst

Comment: Well, for one, I expect the CLCompileTemplate item to have 'AdditionalIncludeDirectories' metadata, among others, which it doesn't.

Comment: How about getting AdditionalIncludeDirectories metadata by using this code?     var collection = new ProjectCollection();
            var project = collection.LoadProject(Item.GetMetadata("Identity"));
          var d=  project.ItemDefinitions.Where(id => id.Key == "ClCompile").First().Value.Metadata.FirstOrDefault(idm=>idm.Name== "AdditionalIncludeDirectories");
            string s = d == null ? "empty" : d.EvaluatedValue;
            ItemLog=s;
            return true;

Comment: Do you try it with my code? Does it meet your requirement?

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time to work on this.

Comment: I post an answer, you can try it when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

The simple sample to get AdditionalIncludeDirectories metadata:

```
    <UsingTask TaskName="LogItem" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll">
        <ParameterGroup>
          <Item ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem" Required="true" />
          <ItemName ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
          <ItemKey ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
          <ItemLog ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
        </ParameterGroup>
        <Task>
          <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
          <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build" />
          <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build" />
          <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Evaluation" />
          <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Utilities" />
          <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[

            var collection = new ProjectCollection();
                var project = collection.LoadProject(Item.GetMetadata("Identity"));
              var d=  project.ItemDefinitions.Where(id => id.Key == "ClCompile").First().Value.Metadata.FirstOrDefault(idm=>idm.Name== "AdditionalIncludeDirectories");
                string s = d == null ? "empty" : d.EvaluatedValue;
                ItemLog=s;
                return true;

           ]]></Code>
        </Task>
      </UsingTask>
<Target Name="CheckTarget">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Targets="SEN_EXTRACT_CONFIG_GetCLCompile" Properties="Configuration=%(ProjectConfiguration.Configuration);Platform=%(ProjectConfiguration.Platform)">
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="CLCompileTemplate" />
    </MSBuild>
    <LogItem Item="@(CLCompileTemplate)" ItemKey="$(UniqueKey)" ItemName="CLCompile">
      <Output TaskParameter="ItemLog" PropertyName="CLCompileTemplateLog" />
    </LogItem>
    <Message Text="output value: $(CLCompileTemplateLog)" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```